# HTML 5 video grey border

Tags: html

On adding a html 5 video tag to a site it displays an initial grey border (from the div) on load, how do I remove this... css border none doesn't work!

```
<video id="media" width="37.5rem" height="25rem" controls>
<source src="/media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
```

Comment: could you please show the complete code with div?

Comment: `<Source>` doesnt have an end tag

Comment: Sorry it is not a full div it is purely and id for the purpose of a JS function, how do I close a source tag

Comment: No need o close it. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: the grey border is there on page load maybe for 5 seconds then goes but looks unsightly. it appears like its the edge of the video file as it remains for the same 5secs when removing the id. Anyway to get shot of this

Comment: Just tried your code with no custom style https://jsfiddle.net/mx1e0ckg/. Didnt find any border

Comment: In which browser are you seeing this? Is it only in one specific one or in all? Also, if you could create a code snippet for us to look at, that would also be very helpful.